A partir de genexus 18, donde puedo encontrar la herramienta gxconfig.exe que permite cambiar las credenciales de la base de datos?
En el siguiente link indican de la herramienta gxconfig.exe para cambiar las credenciales de la base de datos:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?14912,Gxconfig,
Pero estoy usando genexus 18 y en la carpeta bin no la encuentro y tampoco esta en todo el directorio raiz.
Me pueden indicar donde obtengo esa herramienta ? o cual es la forma o método que se debe hacer para el cambio de las credenciales ??
Gracias.

Que generador estás usando? Porque gxconfig es únicamente para net framework. Si generas net core tienes que usar la utilidad de encriptación y modificar el appsetting manualmente.
En esta página lo dice https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?39853,.NET+Platform+restrictions

Muchas gracias !
